# BIRT runtime error - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: out-of-memory, birt

I am using BIRT to run a report on a server that is known to be able to handle relatively large datasets. However, this report will not run correctly and throws the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I am not sure why a memory limit would be reached given the nature of this report. It is returning approximately 20 rows and does limited pre-processing of the data.

The full error is below:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
Hide Exception Stack Trace
Stack Trace:
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2256)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:270)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:86)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1325)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:158)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtChangeParameterActionHandler.runReport(BirtChangeParameterActionHandler.java:58)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractChangeParameterActionHandler.__execute(AbstractChangeParameterActionHandler.java:53)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleChangeParameter(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:100)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1805)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Also this happens when I export data in Excel format. Any news? thanks.

Comment: I never solved it nor do I have any idea what I used as a workaround. Too long ago. Sorry.

Comment: Very Strange: The report successfully runs in a box with 7.5GB RAM but fails in a box with 16GB RAM. Has anyone found a solution

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved at last
setenv.bat or setenv.sh runs only if you use the startup scripts to start the tomcat. If you have setup tomcat as a service the setenv will not be called.

After you setup the tomcat service
execute the tomcat8w.exe (I am using tomcat version 8, use the executable corresponding to your version)

you get a window, click on the java tab
set the Initial memory pool and maximum memory pool. Your birt report starts working fine

The understanding is that you have use the default service name when installing tomcat as a service.
If you have provided a different name, then use

tomcat8w //MS//

This will allow you to configure the JVM for tomcat.

Check the [Apache Howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) link for more information